# deleted s3 bucket then recreated it in another region. Now Cors Upload is getting error Only AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 is supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, pre-signed-url

so i deleted my s3 bucket and then recreated it in another region. I added back my block public access settings ( All public access is blocked)

added back my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "<hidden>",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt<hidden>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<hidden>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<hidden>"
        }
    ]
}
```

and added back my cors policy

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            <hidden>
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

and my principal user which my boto3 uses access keys and secret keys to do work with is back on the bucket

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                my nice buckets
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The point I am making is nothing has changed. I just changed the bucket region and now the cors presigned post upload that was working while I had my bucket in the old region isn't. I keep getting the error mentioned in the title. Its very weird and AWS has not gotten back to me yet.

The full error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Only AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 is supported</Message><ArgumentName>X-Amz-Algorithm</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>undefined</ArgumentValue><RequestId></RequestId><HostId></HostId></Error>
```

it says the signature is undefined but why?

I moved the bucket from `us-east-2` to `us-east-1` to make the bucket play nice with a`aws elastic transcoder`

here is the full code being used to generate the presigned post

```
import boto3
class PrivateGeneratePresignedUrlResource(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        userid = kwargs.get('userid')
        contentpostid = kwargs.get('contentpostid')
        contenttype = kwargs.get('contentype')
        if checkIfUserEmailIsValidated(request.user):
            if checkIfUserIsContentCreator(request.user):
                if checkIfUserIsActive(request.user):
                    user = getUserObject(request.user)
                    if user.id == int(userid):
                        contentcreatorobject = user.contentcreatoruserid
                        get_object_or_404(ContentFeedPost, id = int(contentpostid), contentcreator= contentcreatorobject)
                        keytime = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S%f')
                        randomkey = random.randrange(10000000000000, 99999999999999)
                        awskey = keytime + str(randomkey) + 'raw'
                        fields = {'acl': 'bucket-owner-full-control',
                                  'x-amz-meta-user': userid,
                                  'x-amz-meta-contentpost': contentpostid,
                                  'x-amz-meta-rawbucketkey': str(awskey),
                                  'content-type': contenttype}
                        conditions = [
                            {'acl': 'bucket-owner-full-control'},
                            {'x-amz-meta-user': userid},
                            {'x-amz-meta-contentpost': contentpostid},
                            {'x-amz-meta-rawbucketkey': str(awskey)},
                            {'content-type': contenttype}
                        ]
                        s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                                          aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                          aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                                          region_name=AWS_US_1_REGION)
                        post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
                            Bucket=AWS_S3_SHOFI_KIRKE_UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME,
                            Key=awskey,
                            Fields=fields,
                            Conditions=conditions
                        )
                        print('here is the post>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
                        print(post)
                        return Response({
                            'url': post['url'],
                            'fields': post['fields'],
                            'uriroot': AWS_S3_SHOFI_KIRKE_UPLOAD_BUCKET_ROOT_URI
                        })
                    context = {'param userid is not request user id'}
                    return Response(context, status=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED )
                context = {'content creator is not active'}
                return Response(context, status=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
            context = {'user is not content creator'}
            return Response(context, status=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        context = {'user needs to validate email'}
        return Response(context, status=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: What region did you use before and what region are you using now? Newer regions enforce newer security signatures. How are you generating the pre-signed URL (can you show us the code)? It is possible that the code is using an old SDK.

Comment: just edited the question to address what you asked. Thank you for looking into it

Comment: Mmm, us-east-1 is the oldest, so that isn't the problem. Are you using a recent version of boto? Current version is: 1.20.13

Comment: Yes. This change was done only a few days ago